# What are real life uses of node.js compared to python twisted

Tags: node.js

I am new to node.js. What I have learned from reading that node.js permits writing C like / console programs in java script language.

I an wondering which problem node.js solve. One could be async.http / tcp servers. What is industrial / commercial application of node.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Speed. Node.js is quite fast. System utilities, daemons, parsers, async servers... Even web applications.
As for me, I use node.js to build console utilities and testcases for JS libraries.